# RN Android: button takes too much space when text on 2 lines

Tags: react-native, expo

I have this button

```
const TestButton = ({ text }) => (
  <View
    style={{
      width: '100%',
      marginTop: 10,
      padding: 10,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }}>
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        padding: 10,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}>
      <Text numberOfLines={2}>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

I want the button to be the smallest possible, and centered.

### Android

[image]

On Android, as you can see it's not really the case. For the 3 case we can clearly see that the button (green) is much larger than it should be and takes all available space.

### iOS

[image]

On iOS as you can see it seems to work as I expect.

Is this a bug? Are there any workaround to solve this problem on Android?

Here is an [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/BygrgMRNM) to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const TestButton = ({ text }) => (
  <View
    style={{
      width: '100%',
      marginTop: 10,
      padding: 10,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }}>
    <View
      style={{
        padding: 10,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}>
      <Text numberOfLines={2}
       style = {{
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        padding:10
       }}>
        {text}
      </Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: @SebastienLorber i also have this padding:10 sometimes not working . why i dont know in ios its works fine .in android is a bug i think

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my issue with wrapping my labels into container:

```css
  itemContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    marginHorizontal: 25,
    paddingVertical: 15,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  itemView: {
    width: "100%"
  },
  newsTitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: darkBlue,
    paddingRight: 20,
    fontFamily: "Helvetica-middle",
    borderColor: darkBlue,
    borderWidth: 1
  },
  newsChannel: {
    paddingTop: 10,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontFamily: "Helvetica",
    color: darkGrey
  },
```

```html
  return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemContainer}>
        <View style={styles.itemView}>
          <Text style={styles.newsTitle}>{news.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.newsChannel}>{newsChannelTitle}</Text>
        </View>

        <ArrowIcon />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
```